# How can I save the checkbox values on all wordpress pages for the current user?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and I have a question
How can I save the checkbox values on all wordpress pages for the current user? For all other users, the code does not apply.
I have a code
     `<form method="POST">
     Option One: <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1" <?php 
     if(isset($_POST['check1'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
    Option Two: <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="2" <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['check2'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
    <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>`

```
 `<?php

if(isset($_POST['check1'])){

echo '22222';


}

elseif(isset($_POST['check2'])){


echo '3455';

}

?>`
```

but when you go to another page, everything is reset

how do i fix it?
Tell me please

Comment: you need to store the POST in $_SESSION

Comment: Try a cookie or write it into a database

Answer (score 0):

You might work with php session or javascript localstorage.

Working with tabs will be a right solution, or else, storage right here

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['check'])){
  $_SESSION['customer_values']['check_1'] = "VALUE1";
}

if(isset($_POST['check2'])){
  $_SESSION['customer_values']['check_2'] = "VALUE2";
}
```

Comment: Why that nothing has changed
when you go to any post, everything is reset

Comment: in your current form, you need to validate <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1" <?php if ( isset($_SESSION['customer_values']['check1'] ) ) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?> />

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but the skin lacks commas and a lot of extra spaces.
<input type = "checkbox" name = "check1" value = "1" <?php if (isset ($_SESSION ['customer_values'] ['check1'])) echo 'checked = "checked" '; ?> />
but the code still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but the code in the comments is buggy
Therefore, I will write it to him here

```
 <form method="POST">
Option One: <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1" <?php if ( isset($_SESSION  
['customer_values'] ['check1'] ) ) echo 'checked = "checked" '; ?> />
Option Two: <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="1" <?php if ( isset 
($_SESSION ['customer_values'] ['check2'] ) ) echo 'checked = "checked" '; ?> />  

<br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['check1'])){
$_SESSION['customer_values']['check1'] = "VALUE1";
}

if(isset($_POST['check2'])){
$_SESSION['customer_values']['check2'] = "VALUE2";
}



?>
```

You had this code, if yes then for some reason it does not work